# After upgrade fontawesome library icon not showing?

Tags: drupal-7, font-awesome

I use font awesome library 3.0.1 then use icon it show completely after that i upgrade library to 3.2 then refresh page icon not showing.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade the library copy all the content from new library and paste it in our old fontawesome library this will update fontawesome **css, font and less** file.

This work fine for me.

Hope it will work for you.